# ELM get and decode two or more fields

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I'm newbie in elm. Now i trying to make get request.

The request returns me an array of objects. In fact, these are search results, where each object in the array = price and productId.

Structure:

```
data: [
        {
          price: 7,
          productId: 12
        },
        {
          price: 4,
          productId: 2
        }
    ]
```

At the moment I just geting an array of prices:

```
getApiPrice: Flags -> Cmd Msg
getApiPrice params =
    Http.send NewPrice (Http.get (apiUrlConstructor params) Decoders.priceDecoder)

priceDecoder: Decode.Decoder (List Float)
priceDecoder =
    Decode.field "data" (Decode.list (Decode.field "priceRub" Decode.float))
```

Then I just sort the array and take the first element (I need the result with the lowest price value)

Now I needed the productId field. Can I do the sorting right in the request to get the object (or tuple) with the lowest price and the productId of it.

Answer (score 3):

One of the options would be decoding your data into list of product records intead of list of prices. Then it will be flexible enough to get the `price`, `productId` and any other field that can appear in the future:

```
type alias Product = { price : Float, productId: Int }

productDecoder : Decode.Decoder Product
productDecoder =
    Decode.map2 Product
        (Decode.field "price" Decode.float)
        (Decode.field "productId" Decode.int)

decoder: Decode.Decoder (List Product)
decoder =
    Decode.field "data" (Decode.list productDecoder)
```

I assume that you're sorting the list in the `update` function on handling `NewPrice` message. I can be still done there by using [List.sortBy](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/List#sortBy) function. Or the list can be sorted straight in the `decoder` with a bit of help of `Decode.map`:

```
decoder: Decode.Decoder (List Product)
decoder =
    Decode.map (List.sortBy .price) (Decode.field "data" (Decode.list productDecoder))
```

Now a sorted list is received within `NewPrice` message. The only step remains - to get the first element using [List.head](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/List#head) again either in the `update` function or in the `decoder`:

```
decoder: Decode.Decoder (Maybe Product)
decoder =
    Decode.map ((List.sortBy .price) >> List.head) (Decode.field "data" (Decode.list productDecoder))
```

Here's an [ellie-app](https://ellie-app.com/3VfMJ4PF23Ca1) for demonstrating purposes.